# If I disconnect this fitting, will I have to re-tape when I reconnect it?

Tags: plumbing, fitting

My dishwasher's hot water supply line is braided stainless steel going to a separate cut-off valve. I assumed it would be a compression fitting, but it looks like it's been tapped with PTFE tape, and I've read in numerous places that you're not supposed to tape compression fittings.

[image: Hot water cut-off with what looks like PTFE tape]

It's been like this since I moved in 8 years ago. I rented the property for three years before buying it from my landlord, and (a) I know that he liked to save money by doing work himself, and (b) I can fully believe he incorrectly taped a compression fitting because he didn't know better.

If I disconnect the supply line (e.g., to replace the dishwasher) how do I reconnect it properly?

Comment: that looks suspiciously like a quick connect type

Answer (score 2):

Typically in the US, those water supply line shutoffs (like yours) have a male threaded "compression" outlet. New ones come with the threaded male outlet, a soft metal compressible "ferrule" and a nut that fits over the ferrule.  In days gone by, the line running to faucet etc. would actually be a hard or semi hard metal tube attached via a real compression connection using the ferrule and compression nut onto this threaded outlet.

In that case, the watertight seal is a metal-to-metal outlet/ferrule/metal tube unthreaded seal (the threads are used only to drive the outer compression nut). Since the threads are not making the seal, no tape/dope is necessary on the threads, but wouldn't hurt as long as it does not get into the ferrule sealing area.

***Nowadays, almost always the line running to the faucet etc is a flexible braided hose with attached nut on the end matching the shutoff outlet's "compression" drive threading, but not actually making a true compression connection.*** On first installation, one first discards the ferrule and loose nut that came with the male end. Instead of a true compression connection, the hose-attached nut makes a standard tubing end seal using a rubber gasket inside the base of the nut. ***There is no ferrule and no metal-to-metal seal; as the seal is with the rubber washer inside, the threading is also not part of the seal.*** Thus again, teflon tape or pipe dope is not necessary but doesn't hurt unless it gets between the tubing end and the rubber gasket.

Such rubber-gasketed seals are vulnerable to over-tightening, which can dislodge the rubber gasket and cause a leak. Proper tightening of such a connection is to first hand tighten nut with fingers so the male outlet is seated against the bottom gasket, then use a wrench to tighten an additional 1/2 turn or so.

You will not need teflon tape or pipe dope when you re-connect. However, since the inner plastic/rubber tubing in the braided supply hose degrades over time, it's strongly recommended to purchase a new replacement braided hose for your work.